# Developing a video player app

Tags: android-video-player

I want to build a video player on android platform which is actually for E-learning purpose and thus here protection and piracy of videos is major concern. The video player will be connected to a server which has all the videos and only on subscribing to the video, the user can download the video. 
But now i need to protect the videos from being shared also. So what I thought is to make a hidden password protected folder from my app which would contain only the downloaded videos, so that even if someone accesses the folder cant get the videos in them, and thus piracy will reduce.Here the password is not available to the user also because  the file  should only be played on my media player which has the decrypt code. No other player can play that file. 
My major doubt is do you think this idea is feasible?? Actually I am new to Android development so if you could guide me as to how could this be done?? I plan to use either the media player class or the VideoView class for the same? What do you suggest would be better for this application? 
Is is possible to stop the installation of any app without internet connection, even if the user has the .apk file??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bundling the video with your app - why not host all the media on a remote server? The users can then download/stream from there after authentication.

Comment: No, its like the users who are subscribed to the videos get the videos on their SD card and then can view those downloaded videos anytime without internet connection and also any no. times. Further they can also download other videos from the server by paying for them.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Just have the users download ONLY those videos they bought. You could setup some kind of verification on the server to check who is downloading what.

Comment: But the downloaded videos need to be protected so that the user doesn't distribute to other people, thus i need to password protect(from developer's point of view) the folder where the downloaded videos are stored on SD Card.

Comment: Try to keep the video password protected in some zip file on the user's SD card? Only the app needs to be able to extract the file for viewing - delete it after it's done. There would still be issues to solve, but it can be done. However - this discussion is moving off-topic here. If you want to discuss product ideas/implementation do so elsewhere.